# Revit IFC export missing something

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit

I tried to export IFC from Revit but found something missing, e.g., texture.
Does IFC support texture elements?

Software: Revit

Comment: quick question, are you using Forge Model Derivative API to export IFC?

Comment: No, used revit export

Comment: you mean you are exporting IFC direct from Revit product, and found something missing?

Comment: yes, exported IFC directly from revit and imported into bimserver, then found texture missing.

Comment: This seems a Revit product issue, nothing related to the Forge API, may require your Revit file to check. would suggest to try https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-architecture-forum/bd-p/133

Comment: I tried forge api and the result was the same, missing texture, so I guess both revit and forge don't support IFC very well, or maybe IFC doesn't support texture either.

Comment: Here is the link discussing about the issue since last year. https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/ifc4-material-texture-images/td-p/8075324

Comment: I checked the spec of IFC 4.2 which supports texture like IfcImageTexture, IfcBlobTexture and IfcPixelexture.

Comment: @ZhongWu any comment?